# Excel Power Pivot Sums are off

Tags: microsoft-excel-365, powerpivot, microsoft-powerbi

For work I am extracting data from a huge .csv file (1.754.488 rows), including revenue numbers for different customers at different months. When I load this .csv file into Power BI and create a matrix there, the sums of the revenue of the respective months is correct as it should be. When I load the exact same .csv file into Power Pivot in Excel (Office 365) with the same import options, the revenue sums for the respective months do not match anymore. Does anybody know where the mistake could be with the Power Pivot import? Does Power Pivot leave out some rows?

I load the file into Power BI using the Power Query Editor. It looks like this:

[image]

In Power Pivot, I use the manage connections field, like this:

[image]

I use the same formatting:

[image]

The number of rows after import are identical. This is Power BI:

[image]

This is Power Pivot:

[image]

All calculations were done before, the programs really should just display the data in the .csv file. But when I display the values, they differ.

This is the Power BI Matrix:

[image]

This is the Power Pivot table:

[image]

The values for the begin of the period and end of the period match up, but the difference is only correct in Power BI. In both programs, I gave the difference column the type "decimal number".

Comment: Hi and welcome to SU. Could you edit your post to add some context regarding how you are connecting to the data in Power Pivot? I assume PowerQuery to import into the data model? Have you verified that the row counts are identical between Power BI and Power Pivot? Did you create any special measure in PowerPivot to calculate the revenues? If you have any screenshots you can add to help illustrate, that would be helpful.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the fast response. I added some documentation and clarification.